# Roebic Laboratories, Inc. 32-oz Drain Cleaner Crystals

Tags: bathroom, sink

Product: Roebic Laboratories, Inc. 32-oz Drain Cleaner Crystals

I accidentally poured in almost half the bottle and now my bathroom sink water is not going in at all. What went wrong and how do I fix this issue. Please help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

**Read the [Safety Data Sheet](http://www.roebic.com/pdf/sds/Crystal_Drain_Opener_SDS.pdf)!** You've used a *very* hazardous chemical, which reacts with water to get *very* hot. It can easily get hot enough to boil the water in the drain, causing the boiling hot caustic (**able to dissolve flesh**) solution to spurt out the drain, perhaps onto you! It can also get hot enough to damage pipes, particularly those of plastic, and it could then leak out into a cabinet or onto the floor.

**Do NOT touch any spilled crystals or leaked liquid.** If you have, wash where it touched with a *lot* of vinegar.

The crystals have clumped in the drain, and perhaps the best thing to do would be to fill the sink with **cold** water and let them dissolve, which they will do over time. **Do not push anything into the drain to speed this up.** If this doesn't help, call a plumber, and **warn her or him what you put in the drain**.

Comment: @Djblaze, I hope you've read this before you or anyone else is injured.